# Synonym suggestion in LyX

Tags: synonym, lyx

Is there any package for the **LyX** to give synonym suggestion for words like what Microsoft Word does?

**Quick solution** --> Download .dat and .idx files of your preferred thesaurus at [Here!](http://lyx.org/trac/browser/dictionaries/trunk/thes) put them in a folder. From Tool>Preferences>paths set the thesaurus path to this folder

Comment: A synonym suggestion tool may already be installed, select a word and press `SHIFT + F7` or select Tools > Thesaurus. The language of my document is English (UK) and there is no thesaurus for that language, I need an extra step to select `English` or `English (USA)` in the language drop down list. Apart from this little annoyance, synonym suggestions work. More under help > User's guide > section Thesaurus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a Thesaurus. Yes, LyX has support for this. Read section 6.15 of Help > User's Guide.

Comment: Yes. thanks a lot man. I don't know why this is not mentioned anywhere else. For those who want a lazy solution --> Download .dat and .idx files of your preferred thesaurus at http://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/dictionaries/trunk/thes  put them in one forlder. From Tool>Preferences>paths set the thesaurus path to this folder

Comment: @AmirReza Where else should it be mentioned?

Comment: Maybe in the wiki.or Maybe it's my problem that I google everything before even reading the user's guide!

Comment: I think the key was to google "thesaurus lyx". The first link for me was the announcement of the new feature in 2.0:

Comment: And if you do read the User's Guide, you won't regret. Even if you just skim it, it will help you remember features later on when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

### For LyX Version 2.3.6

Download files from [This Link](https://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/dictionaries/trunk/thes), just download both files "th_en_GB_v2.idx" & "th_en_GB_v2.dat" for English UK, and copy it to a folder.
Open **LYX -> Tools -> Preferences -> Path -> Thesaurus Dictionaries -> Browse to the above made folder**. To set Keyboard shortcut Alt + 1; **LYX -> Tools -> Preferences -> Editing -> Shortcuts -> Cursor, Mouse and Editing Functions -> thesaurus-entry -> Alt + 1** (Type in Keyboard)